# Can't update firebase collection field - Expected type 'ya', but it was: a custom Ia object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make barbershop web app where costumer can see list of free appointments and when they reserve free appointment I want to delete that field from firebase.

I have a collection which represents one barber.
This is how it looks in firebase.

[image]

As you see radno_vrijeme is object or map in firebase which contains 6 arrays, and in each array there is list of free working hours.

In my function I am able to do everthing except last line where I need to update firebase collection.

```
  const finishReservation = async () => {
    try {
      const freeTimeRef = collection(db, `${barber}`);
      const q = query(freeTimeRef);
      const querySnap = await getDoc(q);
      querySnap.forEach(async (doc) => {
        const radnoVrijeme = doc.data().radno_vrijeme;

        // Find the index of the hour you want to delete
        const index = radnoVrijeme["Mon"].indexOf(hour);
        // Remove the hour from the array
        radnoVrijeme["Mon"].splice(index, 1);
        // Update the document in the collection
        console.log(radnoVrijeme);
        const radnoVrijemeMap = new Map(Object.entries(radnoVrijeme));
        await freeTimeRef.update({ radno_vrijeme: radnoVrijemeMap });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

I tried to pass it as JSON stringified object, but it didn't work. I always get this error :

> "FirebaseError: Expected type 'ya', but it was: a custom Ia object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to fetch multiple documents using a collection reference or query, then you must use `getDocs()`:

```
const finishReservation = async () => {
  try {
    const freeTimeRef = collection(db, `${barber}`);
    const q = query(freeTimeRef);
    const querySnap = await getDocs(q);
    
    const updates = [];
    
    querySnap.forEach((d) => {
      const radnoVrijeme = d.data().radno_vrijeme;    
      const index = radnoVrijeme["Mon"].indexOf(hour);
      radnoVrijeme["Mon"].splice(index, 1);
    
      const radnoVrijemeMap = new Map(Object.entries(radnoVrijeme));
      
      updates.push(updateDoc(d.ref, { radno_vrijeme: radnoVrijemeMap }))
    });
    
    await Promise.all(updates);
    console.log("Documents updated")
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

`getDoc()` is used to fetch a single document using a document reference.

Comment: @avuji31 it is. You can't use `getDoc()` with a collection reference.. I've updated my answer with the complet efunction. Can you try running that?

Comment: @avuji31 right. Can you try the updated statement? So the original issue was indeed `getDoc()` ?

Comment: FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Map object (found in field radno_vrijeme in document Ana Lončar/pBrrw16ZIO5UeFhfhBDv)

Comment: @avuji31 that's a totally different issue. Why not try `{ radno_vrijeme: radnoVrijeme }` and remove the `radnoVrijemeMap` logic? I don't see its use case there

Comment: I tried this solution because of chatGPT, I tried many things. It works now, but I also tried just radno_vrijeme : radnoVrijeme, but it didn't work, now it works with your code. It was something with update function, as I said everything works except update line. Thanks

Comment: The AI does not know about all latest updates. `.update()` is older syntax for `updateDoc()` that ChatGPT used.